# How to install MS Combat Flight Simulator 2 in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Just installed 12.04 on offline home build computer - completely new to Ubuntu - would appreciate advice.

Comment: You could possibly run the game under windows compatibility layer "wine" if you wish. http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8018

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run it with wine.
Just install wine with the following and then install/run the program like you normally would:

> sudo apt-get install wine

See [this page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8018) for more info on wine and MS Combat Flight Simulator 2

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can do it with either [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), or running windows as a virtual machine using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Now Wine lists that the game hasn't been tested with 12.04, see [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=13371), now that being said, I would recommend using VirtualBox.